ESTA “Is your travel to the US occurring in transit to another country”
I made a mistake on my US ESTA application. I plan to go to New York in 2 months time for a little birthday trip. On the ESTA TRANSIT question “Is your travel to the US occurring in transit to another country?” I answered “YES”… stupidly thinking it was about my connection flight from GLA to AMS to US (NEW YORK)
Unfortunately, I have already paid and submitted my application at https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/?forceNav=true so I cannot make any changes. I’m literally so sick with worry waiting to see even if I get approved, would I be denied entry in the US?

The FAQ states Any other mistakes may be corrected or updated by clicking “Check Individual Status” under “Check ESTA Status”. If the traveler made a mistake in answering the eligibility questions, please click on the CBP Info Center Link at the bottom of each page. Have you tried either of these?

@Relaxed Thank you for your respond! I have now contacted the CBP under CBP Info Center as you mentioned above. I’ll update here of the outcomes! Fingers crossed

@Relaxed I'm fairly certain that “Is your travel to the US occurring in transit to another country?” is not an "eligibility question."  The eligibility questions are those about your criminal history, travel history, and so on, that are related to the statutory grounds of inadmissibility or of ineligibility for the visa waiver program.

@Nino Did you receive your authorization to travel?  You could just submit another application and pay again

@Midavalo Hi there! Not yet, I keep checking the status and it’s still reading “pending”. I did think about making another application but I don’t know… won’t that look a little suspicious somehow?

@phoot Then it should be possible to edit the value directly? That's how I understand the sentence I quoted but it wasn't clear to me whether the OP tried either of these and I cannot try it myself (nor would I want to) so I just left a comment…

I wanted to update the reply that I received from CBP so it may help someone in the future with a similar problem as me.
⚠️Thank you for contacting the Traveler Communications Center.
Please review the information below and reply directly to this email if this general information does not resolve your inquiry. If your inquiry has already been resolved, please disregard this email.
Error in your Date of Birth:
If you have made a mistake in your date of birth on your ESTA application, your incorrect application will need to be cancelled in order to re-apply. If this is the case, please respond to this email with your name, date of birth, and passport number to complete the cancellation request. You will then need to complete a new and correct application with the accompanying fee.
When you have to apply for a new ESTA:
An ESTA application must contain correct pertinent biographical data.  This includes full name, date of birth, citizenship, place of birth, gender, and passport information. If you are or have ever been a citizen of another country, this must be included on your ESTA application.
If you have made an error in your parents’ biographical information, you will need to submit an updated ESTA application.
Once an application has been submitted, no changes can be made because the ESTA application is considered an official document.
If your application contains incorrect information for any of the above, you must submit a new application at: https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta. If an application that contains incorrect data is part of a group application, only the application with the incorrect data needs to be resubmitted. There is a fee associated with each application submitted. Erroneous or incorrect information can cause delays at check-in and/or upon arrival in the United States.
A new ESTA application is also required if your responses to any of the ESTA eligibility questions (page 5 of the ESTA application) change.
If you are unable to submit a new application, please respond to this email with your name, date of birth, and passport number so that we can submit a cancellation request. You will then need to complete a new and correct application with the accompanying fee.
When you DO NOT have to apply for a new ESTA:
A change or error in employment, home address, work address, phone number, email address, travel itinerary, transit status, travel address, or in the point of contact information does not require that a new application be submitted, or that an existing application be updated. However, please have the correct information readily available, as it may be requested during the inspection process.
